# AWS Amplify CustomerError: Cannot read 'next' version in package.json

Tags: next.js, aws-amplify

I'm trying to deploy a simple Next.JS app that has just a front-end with no back-end or database connections to AWS Amplify but I keep getting this error on the build:

```
2023-05-20T17:00:51.907Z [INFO]: # Checking for Git submodules at: /codebuild/output/src963349001/src/static/.gitmodules
2023-05-20T17:00:51.911Z [ERROR]: !!! CustomerError: Cannot read 'next' version in package.json.
```

I don't understand why it can't read the next version. It's right here in the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "one-two-static",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build && next export",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "20.2.1",
    "@types/react": "18.2.6",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.4",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
    "eslint": "8.41.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.3",
    "next": "13.4.3",
    "postcss": "8.4.23",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.2",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  }
}
```

Here is my next.config.js:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    output: 'standalone',
    experimental: {
      outputStandalone: true,
    }
  }

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Comment: My working version is ` "next": "12.1.5"`. Try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similiar issue and just needed to run `npm install` and then push package.json and package.lock to the repository that deployed to amplify.

It also seems like having `next export` in the package build can cause warning errors, you can try removing this and adding it into the `next.config.js`

Answer (score 1):

Had similar issue and I fixed it by changing package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I had next as a dev-dependency, once i moved it to a dependency, it fixed it for me.